# any limitation to write properties or methods for XPObject?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

Is there any limitation to write properties or methods for `XPObject`?
I want to write some properties or methods to use my data in `XPObject`. I don't want to save them. For example:

```
public List<Tool> Tools
{
    get
    {
        List<Tool> tools= new List<Tool>();
        foreach (var box this.Boxes)
        {
            tools.AddRange(box.tools);
        }
        return tools;
    }
}
```

How shall I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

XPObject will not save read-only properties to the database, so your code is completely correct and should not cause any problem.

In case if you want to add a writable property that should not be stored in the database, you can decorate this property with the [NonPersistent](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.Xpo.NonPersistentAttribute.class) attribute.